# r generate random poisson values

Tags: r, random, data-generation

How do I randomly generate 50% 1s, 30% 2s, 15% 3s and remaining 4s ?

Finally when I do a table , `table(x, useNA = "ifany")`, it should be

```
                         1      2      3    4
                         50     30     15   5
```

I am not sure how to use `rpois` to generate this.

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: That distribution of values is extremely unlikely to have been drawn from a Poisson distribution.

Comment: @IRTFM, what makes you say that ? just curious ?

Comment: @AhirBhairavOrai try `table(rpois(100, 1.5))`.  there's far too little variance in your distribution for it to be Poisson.

Comment: @SamMason, A Poisson variable, mean=variance.

Comment: @AhirBhairavOrai With a mean between 1 and two there should be a bunch of zeroes.

Comment: @AhirBhairavOrai your distribution has mean of 1.75 and variance of ~0.8.  it's possible for 100 draws from a Poisson to like the percentages you're giving, but **extremely** unlikely.  e.g. seeing no zeros out of 100 draws from a Poisson with mean of 1.75 has a probability of ~5e-9 (via `dbinom(0, 100, dpois(0, 1.75))`).  you seem to be asking for something even stronger than this, a Poisson that near one that never has any zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sample.int`.

```
set.seed(42)
x <- sample.int(n=4, size=1e4, replace=TRUE, prob=c(.5, .3, .15, 1 - sum(c(.5, .3, .15))))

proportions(table(x))
# x
#      1      2      3      4 
# 0.5001 0.3001 0.1506 0.0492
```

If you depend on `rpois`, you probably need to invent something with `optimize`.

Comment: Thanks Jay, what is the role of `replace=TRUE` ?

Comment: @AhirBhairavOrai We have *size* > *n*, so we have to put back after the draw which is what `replace=TRUE` does.